# netbeans restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I have been experimenting with Restful web service using jersey in netbeans. I have created a web service and registered it the Netbeans web service, I was able to drag n drop into my client code (all works good), but the problem is the auto generated code does not include a way of working with object

> RestResponse.getDataAsObject(...)

instead of

> RestResponse.getDataAsString(...)

as compared to the generated Facebook code which includes a Facebook library for working with

> RestResponse.getDataAsObject(...)